# How to use GeoDjango with Haystack?

Tags: django, django-haystack, geodjango

I'm trying to use Django (1.5.1) and Haystack (2.0.1) for searching objects that include geolocation information:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels

class GeoModel(geomodels.Model):
    geo_point = geomodels.PointField()
    # Geographic Locator manager
    objects = geomodels.GeoManager()
    ...
```

I need to filter based on the geolocation. The following query works, basically because `GeoModel` is using a `geomodels.GeoManager`:

```
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
...

center = Point(lat, lng)
radius = D(km=100)
GeoModel.objects.all().filter(geo_point__distance_lte=(center, radius))
```

The problem is when I try to use Haystack to filter results based on its geolocation. I made a subclass of SearchView:

```
 from haystack.views import SearchView
 ...

 class MySearchView(SearchView):

    def get_results(self):
        center = Point(lat, lng)
        radius = D(km=100)
        results = super(MySearchView, self).get_results()  # << OK, get all results 
        return results.filter(geo_point__distance_lte=(center, radius))  # << WRONG, no results
```

So, how can I customize Haystack views/form to filter results based on a specific location?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you getting the lat/lng from when you're defining the point? Another thing is that the Point is defined with lng first so it should be center = Point(lng, lat). I got tricked by this too but figured it out when going through the docs - https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/spatial.html#points

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for clarification. I take latitude and longitude from Google Geolocation API and store those values in a Django session. then I build `Point(lat, lng)` with parameters in that order just works, but I'll check the reference you've posted, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a very similar setup (Django 1.5.4, Haystack 2.0.0, Elasticsearch 0.90.0) and this is what I've got:

```python
from haystack.utils.geo import D, Point
from haystack.views import SearchView

class MySearchView(SearchView):
    results = super(MySearchView, self).get_results()
    ...
    lng = -112.0739
    lat = 33.4492
    center = Point(lng, lat)
    radius = D(mi=50)
    results = results.dwithin('geo_point', center, radius)
    ...
    return results
```

An important thing to keep in mind as well is the backend. According to the Haystack backend support matrix (http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backend_support.html#backend-support-matrix) only Solr and Elasticsearch support spatial data.